# ignorar a posição do cursor sobre a barra de rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como ignorar a posição do cursor sobre a barra de rolagem ?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/11/)**

```
var margem = 0;
function criarBarraDeRolagem(){
if ($( document ).height() < $( window ).height()) 
{
return; 
}
var tamanho = $( window ).height() / $( document ).height();
$('#rolagem2').css('top', margem + ($( window ).scrollTop() * tamanho));
$('#rolagem2').height($( window ).height() * tamanho - (margem + margem) );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
criarBarraDeRolagem();
});



var dragObj = null;
$("#rolagem2, body, html").mouseup(function(){
$('body, html').removeClass("unselectable");
dragObj = null;
});

$("#rolagem2").mousedown(function(){
$('body, html').addClass("unselectable");
dragObj = this;
});

$("#rolagem2, body, html").mousemove(function(e){
if( dragObj ) 
{
var move = e.pageY - $("#rolagem").offset().top;
var speed = $(window).height() / $("#rolagem2").height();
$(window).scrollTop(move * speed);
criarBarraDeRolagem();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
}   
});
```

Còdigo funcionando! Só preciso ignorar a posição do cursor sobre a barra de rolagem...

**EDIT: Novo fiddle!!!**
http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/11/

Comment: olha que bom que esta funcionando, poste tambem alguma tentativa sua, testes e afins

Comment: Seria legal explicar o que o código faz, e por que você precisa ignorar essa posição do cursor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var margem = 0;
var diff = 0

function criarBarraDeRolagem() {
    if ($(document).height() < $(window).height() - diff) {
        return;
    }
    if ($("#rolagem").offset().top <= $("#rolagem2").offset().top) {
        var tamanho = $(window).height() / $(document).height();
        var top = margem + ($(window).scrollTop() * tamanho) ;
        $('#rolagem2').css('top', top);
        $('#rolagem2').height($(window).height() * tamanho - (margem + margem));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    criarBarraDeRolagem();
});

var dragObj = null;
$("#rolagem2, body, html").mouseup(function (e) {
    $('body, html').removeClass("unselectable");
    dragObj = null;
});

$("#rolagem2").mousedown(function (e) {
    $('body, html').addClass("unselectable");
    dragObj = this;
    diff = e.pageY - $("#rolagem2").offset().top;
});

$("#rolagem2, body, html").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (dragObj) {
        var move = e.pageY - $("#rolagem").offset().top;
        var speed = $(window).height() / $("#rolagem2").height();
        $(window).scrollTop((move - diff) * speed);
        criarBarraDeRolagem();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/10/)

Comment: mas continua com o mesmo problema...

Comment: não está mais saltando como fazia antes, qual problema você se refere?

Comment: ele salta agora de baixo pra cima

Comment: valew!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: só ficou com um problema, quando coloco margem ele buga de novo, http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/11/ nesse fiddle coloquei 20 de margem e bugou...

Comment: @luigibertaco, ficou bom, mas seria bom tu dar um explicada no que foi feito, para que outras pessoas possam entender.